# Mail Server Domain Serving Multiple Domains

Tags: email, postfix, domain, tld

I am hosting multiple domains on an email server where the SSL certificate is for the root domain name (let's say example.com). The rDNS goes to example.com, but the alias domains on the server are emailhere.com and emailhere2.com for example. Unless someone goes digging, they won't see example.com show up as the emails are going to the alias emails, but it shows up under rDNS for the server IP. If I change example.com to a new TLD domain like 'example.network' along with the rDNS, is there potential to get blacklisted by other email servers even if the alias email domains do not change? Would it be safer to stick to a .com TLD?

To reword, do blacklists care about domain name TLD for the mail server if the alias domain name sending the email is something like '.com'?

Comment: There's potential to get blacklisted by other email servers for _anything_.  I don't understand your specific concern in this case.

Comment: Would an email of domain (an alias) "myemail@emailhost.com" be seen by an email blacklist as coming from "emailhost.com" or the root rDNS domain of "example.network"? I know it goes by server IP, but some TLDs also get blacklisted.

Comment: That would depend on the content of the e-mail being sent.

Comment: But some people choose to filter non-stand TLDs... If that happens, would it be filtered by the rDNS domain or the alias domain?

Comment: It could be filtered be either.  You'd need to ask the people implementing this hypothetical filtering what their hypothetical information sources are... hypothetically.

Comment: Ok, so you sound very skeptical... Do you think it's a non-issue, should I switch to '.network'?

Answer (score 0):

Your emails will not get rejected if you change your email server domain to any TLD, just it must have an rDNS and must be in your main DNS MX or mentioned on the DNS SPF record as an IP address or an include, so other servers will now that it is from your mail server